# Leaves of a tree given the number of internal vertices

Tags: graph, tree, theory

If T is a tree and it is given that the sum of the degrees of the internal (non-leaf) vertices of  T is 50. If T has 13 internal vertices, how many leaves does it have? I am aware that the concept of hand-shaking lemma where the degrees add up to twice the number of edges will come in and there will be (n-1) edges. But I am very confused on how to show the workings of this sum (not any code). Can I expect some help?

Answer (score 0):

So we are given two numbers:

- = the number of internal vertices
- = the sum of degrees of internal vertices

The requested output is:

- = the number of leaves

The sum of the degrees  is twice the number of edges  in the tree, diminished with the number of leaves , since their edges are only counted in the degrees of their parents:

= 2 −

Because the number of edges  in the tree is one less than the number of vertices, we also have:

=  +  − 1

So we can substitute the  in the first equation:

= 2( +  − 1) -  = 2 +  − 2

Now solving this for :

=  + 2 − 2

For your example we have this input:

= 50,  = 13

And so we get:

= 26

Comment: I did not quite comprehend the second equation you used e=i+l-1. Why are we subtracting a 1 here? Thank you – @trincot

Comment: Without that minus one we would count the number of vertices (internal plus leaves). Since a tree has one less edge than vertices we subtract one.